# Execute NPP-Shortcut with NPPexec

Tags: shortcut, nppexec

## NPP shortcut via CMD

Here is my Problem: I want to execute a shortcut of Notepad++ via NPPexec, but I dont know who it works. I hope you can help me.

Thx for ur Answers :D

Comment: Does the shortcut have an entry in Notepad++ menu?

Comment: yes its shortcut number 145 in main menu

Answer (score 0):

To run a command from the menu via nppexec use the `NPP_MENUCOMMAND` command. E.g. to run a the command *Find* from the *Search* menu, you would use the line

```
 NPP_MENUCOMMAND Search/Find
```

in your nppexec scipt.